# R: data.table: aggregation using referencing over time

Tags: r, data.table, aggregation

I have a dataset with periods

```
active <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,3), beg=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 01:10:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00","2018-01-01 01:50:00")), end=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 01:20:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00","2018-01-01 02:00:00")))
> active
   id                 beg                 end 
1:  1 2018-01-01 01:10:00 2018-01-01 01:20:00 
2:  1 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00    
3:  2 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00    
4:  3 2018-01-01 01:50:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
```

during which an id was active. I would like to aggregate across `ids` and determine for every point in

```
time <- data.table(seq(from=min(active$beg),to=max(active$end),by="mins"))
```

the number of IDs that are inactive and the average number of minutes until they get active. That is, ideally, the table looks like

```
>ans
                   time  inactive av.time
 1: 2018-01-01 01:10:00         2      30
 2: 2018-01-01 01:11:00         2      29
...
50: 2018-01-01 02:00:00         0       0
```

I believe this can be done using `data.table` but I cannot figure out the syntax to get the time differences.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52614468/2204410

Comment: Thanks! It helps with the first part, but leaves the second part open. Do you know any source to help there?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can join by a dummy variable to create the Cartesian product of `time` and `active`.  The definitions of `inactive` and `av.time` might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should get you started.  If your data is very large, I agree that `data.table` will be a better way of handling this.

```
library(tidyverse)

time %>% 
  mutate(dummy = TRUE) %>% 
  inner_join({
    active %>% 
      mutate(dummy = TRUE)
    #join by the dummy variable to get the Cartesian product
  }, by = c("dummy" = "dummy")) %>% 
  select(-dummy) %>% 
  #define what makes an id inactive and the time until it becomes active
  mutate(inactive = time < beg | time > end,
         TimeUntilActive = ifelse(beg > time, difftime(beg, time, units = "mins"), NA)) %>% 
  #group by time and summarise
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarise(inactive = sum(inactive),
            av.time = mean(TimeUntilActive, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 51 x 3
        time            inactive av.time
        <dttm>            <int>   <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 01:10:00        3      40
2 2018-01-01 01:11:00        3      39
3 2018-01-01 01:12:00        3      38
4 2018-01-01 01:13:00        3      37
5 2018-01-01 01:14:00        3      36
6 2018-01-01 01:15:00        3      35
7 2018-01-01 01:16:00        3      34
8 2018-01-01 01:17:00        3      33
9 2018-01-01 01:18:00        3      32
10 2018-01-01 01:19:00        3      31
```

Comment: Thanks -- the dummy solution is ineed interesting and I will look into this. However, the data is indeed quite large, spanning several years and several thousand ids. If anyone has a `data.table`solution this would help greatly.