# R: merge Dataframes on date and unique IDs with conditions distributed across many rows in R

Tags: r, date, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on a conditional relationship between several dates associated with unique identifiers but distributed across different observations (rows).

I have two large datasets with unique identifiers. One dataset has 'enter' and 'exit' dates (alongside some other variables).

```
> df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4), 
enter.date=c('5/07/2015','7/10/2015','8/25/2017','9/1/2016','1/05/2018','5/01/2016','4/08/2017'), 
+                   exit.date = c('7/1/2015', '10/15/2015', '9/03/2017', '9/30/2016', '6/01/2019', 
'5/01/2017', '6/08/2017'));
> dcis <- grep('date$',names(df1));
> df1[dcis] <- lapply(df1[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
> df1;
  ID enter.date  exit.date
1  1 2015-05-07 2015-07-01
2  1 2015-07-10 2015-10-15
3  1 2017-08-25 2017-09-03
4  2 2016-09-01 2016-09-30
5  2 2018-01-05 2019-06-01
6  3 2016-05-01 2017-05-01
7  4 2017-04-08 2017-06-08
```

and the other has "eval" dates.

```
> df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,3,4), eval.date=c('10/30/2015', 
'10/10/2016','9/10/2019','5/15/2018','1/19/2015'));
> df2$eval.date<-as.Date(df2$eval.date, '%m/%d/%Y')
> df2;
  ID  eval.date
1  1 2015-10-30
2  2 2016-10-10
3  2 2019-09-10
4  3 2018-05-15
5  4 2015-01-19
```

I am trying to calculate the average interval of time from 'exit' to 'eval' for each individual in the dataset. However, I only want those 'evals' that come after a given individual's 'exit' and before the next 'enter' for that individual (there are no 'eval' observations between enter and exit for a given individual), if such an 'eval' exists.

In other words, I'm trying to get an output that looks like this from the two dataframes above.

```
> df3 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,3), enter.date=c('7/10/2015','9/1/2016','1/05/2018','5/01/2016'), 
+                   exit.date = c('10/15/2015', '9/30/2016', '6/01/2019', '5/01/2017'),
+                   assess.date=c('10/30/2015', '10/10/2016', '9/10/2019', '5/15/2018'));
> dcis <- grep('date$',names(df3));
> df3[dcis] <- lapply(df3[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
> df3$time.diff<-difftime(df3$exit.date, df3$assess.date)
> df3;
  ID enter.date  exit.date assess.date time.diff
1  1 2015-07-10 2015-10-15  2015-10-30  -15 days
2  2 2016-09-01 2016-09-30  2016-10-10  -10 days
3  2 2018-01-05 2019-06-01  2019-09-10 -101 days
4  3 2016-05-01 2017-05-01  2018-05-15 -379 days
```

Once I perform the merge finding the averages is easy enough with

```
> aggregate(df3[,5], list(df3$ID), mean)
  Group.1       x
1       1  -15.0 
2       2  -55.5 
3       3 -379.0
```

but I'm really at a loss as to how to perform the merge. I've tried to use leftjoin and fuzzyjoin to perform the merge per the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289405/dplyr-left-join-by-less-than-greater-than-condition) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353595/checking-if-date-is-between-two-dates-in-r), but I'm inexperienced at R and couldn't figure it out. I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through it - thanks!

A few other descriptive notes about the data: each ID may have some number of rows associated with it in each dataframe. df1 has enter dates which mark the beginning of a service delivery and exit dates that mark the end of a service delivery. All enters have one corresponding exit. df2 has eval dates. Eval dates can occur at any time when an individual is *not* receiving the service. There may be many evals between one period of service delivery and the next, or there may be no evals.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the sqldf package. Assuming that for each ID the date ranges are in ascending order, you might use it like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4), enter.date=c('5/07/2015','7/10/2015','8/25/2017','9/1/2016','1/05/2018','5/01/2016','4/08/2017'), exit.date = c('7/1/2015', '10/15/2015', '9/03/2017', '9/30/2016', '6/01/2019', 
'5/01/2017', '6/08/2017'));
dcis <- grep('date$',names(df1));
df1[dcis] <- lapply(df1[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
df1;

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,3,4), eval.date=c('10/30/2015', 
'10/10/2016','9/10/2019','5/15/2018','1/19/2015'));
df2$eval.date<-as.Date(df2$eval.date, '%m/%d/%Y')
df2;

library(sqldf)

df1 = unsplit(lapply(split(df1, df1$ID, drop=FALSE), function(df) {
    df$next.date = as.Date('2100-12-31')
    if (nrow(df) > 1)
        df$next.date[1:(nrow(df) - 1)] = df$enter.date[2:nrow(df)]
    df
}), df1$ID)


sqldf('
select df1.*, df2.*, df1."exit.date" - df2."eval.date" as "time.diff"
  from df1, df2
  where df1.ID == df2.ID
    and df2."eval.date" between df1."exit.date"
    and df1."next.date"')


  ID enter.date  exit.date  next.date ID..5  eval.date time.diff
1  1 2015-07-10 2015-10-15 2017-08-25     1 2015-10-30       -15
2  2 2016-09-01 2016-09-30 2018-01-05     2 2016-10-10       -10
3  2 2018-01-05 2019-06-01 2100-12-31     2 2019-09-10      -101
4  3 2016-05-01 2017-05-01 2100-12-31     3 2018-05-15      -379
```